# How is a char[] loaded into memory in a DLL

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm embedding binary data (a pdf document) into a shared library using a unsigned char[] variable. That is, I have a C file containing something like this:

unsigned char large_data[] = {0x24, 0x23...};
int sizeofLargeData = sizeof(large_data);

The large data can be many megabytes. My question is, when the shared library is loaded by an application, is this data loaded into memory?

Answer (score 2):

When a shared library is loaded by an application (either through an implicit dependency or an explicit call to [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows or [`dlopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) on POSIX systems), the loader *maps* the entirety of the DLL's contents (its executable code and its global variable segments) into memory in the process's virtual address space, but it doesn't immediately load all of the data by reading it from disk.

Modern OSes like Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X use [*demand paging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) to load modules.  What this means is that the data doesn't actually get read from disk until it's accessed.  When you access data on a page that hasn't been loaded yet (say, by calling an exported function for the first time or by accessing a global variable form the module for the first time), a page fault exception is generated.  The OS handles the page fault, loads the corresponding code or data from disk, and then resumes the program from the fault location; since the data is now loaded, the program no longer page faults upon resuming.

Hence, if you have megabytes of data in the shared object and the program never accesses it, you never pay the I/O cost of having to load those megabytes from disk.  It's still technically mapped into memory—you can access it any time you want without any system calls—but the data hasn't actually been read off disk.

Comment: Thanks, great. Your answer is specific to windows however.
Perhaps it works similarly on Linux and other systems.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson: For some reason I thought the original question was specifically about Windows, but apparently it isn't.  In any case, the answer is the same for any OS that supports demand paging, which modern OSes do.