# How to store large chunk of data in a shared library, without loading it

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I want to store a binary 'blob' of data in a shared library (x-platform), using C++. At the moment, my binary data is stored as an unsigned char array containing hex values, together with a helper giving the size of the data.

```
unsigned char large_data[] = {0x24, 0x23...}; 
int sizeofLargeData = sizeof(large_data);
```

the corresponding header file looks like:
  RR_PLUGIN_DECLSPEC extern unsigned char pdf_docs[];
  RR_PLUGIN_DECLSPEC extern size_t sizeofPDF;

Now, instead of having large_data being a global object, with the potential of being loaded into memory as the shared library is loaded, how can I set it up so that the memory is only allocated when needed, and also, can be disposed of?

A related post, [How is a char[] loaded into memory in a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025963/how-is-a-char-loaded-into-memory-in-a-dll) , had a comment suggesting creating local data, sounding like the way to go, but the comment was deleted for some reason.

Comment: How exactly do you expect to fill your newly allocated array?  If you are going to copy from `large_data`, then you are using up twice the memory (one to load in `large_data` and one for your temporary array). If you know how to dynamically fill the array (ie read from a file), then where is the problem?  Just have some globally accessible variable that you can check to see if `large_data` has been initialized, if not, load in the data from somewhere else.

Comment: The data is not read from file. The data is embedded in the shared library. Question is how to be able to create and dispose of it dynamically, that is all. Currently, the data is global and may be loaded as the shared library is loaded, and for sure loaded when the data is accessed. After that, I have no way to dispose (delete) of it.

Comment: I'm saying, 1. how are you going to create it dynamically to begin with?  You have these pre-calculated values that are significant to you ... where are you going to store them when they aren't being used?  The linked answer says they won't even be loaded into memory until you access them anyway.  Do you have a problem with this data being stored on disk?  2. if you want to free up space, I don't know if there is a way to unload individual variables from a DLL without unloading the whole DLL. If the OS needs memory, it will page your data to disk.

Comment: You are asking the same question that I am asking.
As for their storage, they are to be embedded in the shared library, probably with local scope. The problem with global scope, as you also suggest is how to free?
And yes, I have a problem reading them from disk.
I can see having a function creating data locally and returning a pointer to it. The client could after using the data call a dispose function, with the pointer as argument. But right now, I don't see how to do this.. And that is my question.

Comment: I haven't tried this but one possible way is create 2 DLLS -- one with only data and maybe 1 fake function; and the other your real functions.  The data DLL will get loaded when it is needed. And then you can manually unload the data DLL when done.